# New to HTML and CSS, links are moving when hovered over

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get 3 images that are also links to other pages, however when I hover over them, they jump out of place.

Any help?

my CSS looks like this for my second media query, and I would need it to inherit throughout.

```
#section_container_bottom figure {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;     
    }

#section_container_bottom img {
    width: 25%;
    margin: 3%;
    }

#section_container_bottom img a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover {
        display: block;
        }
```

this is the HTML

```
<section id="section_container_bottom">
    <figure>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="Sources/USE/latest-colors.png" alt="An overview of the latest colors available at Paint Republic"></a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="Sources/USE/inspiration.png" alt="Some inspiration provided by Paint Republic for you when looking to repaint in your own home"></a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="Sources/USE/color-expert.png" alt="Contact one of the color experts that are available through Paint Republic"></a>
        <div class="clear_float"></div>
    </figure>
</section>
```

Am I having a display issue with display:block?

Comment: Could you create a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: the problem is the `display:block`, it removes the default behaviour of images.. `display:inline`

Comment: That will be because you are changing the images from `display: inline;` to `display: block;` on hover.

Comment: Why you have on hover display: block, what you want to achieve? And yes, is the display: block

Comment: It works with the Display: inline property, I wanted to make it a simple on hover transition that will change the opacity of the images when hovered over. Have got it, Thank you very much.

Comment: I have undeleted the request but have also figured it out alone, will update my question with my new one and we can discuss :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please change following line of code in your css

**CSS**

```
#section_container_bottom a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover {
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS selectors need to be repeated after a comma.

```
#section_container_bottom img a:link,
#section_container_bottom img a:visited,
#section_container_bottom img a:active,
#section_container_bottom img a:hover {
    display: block;
}
```